# RichTextBox horizontal scroll not working

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, richtextbox, windows-forms-designer

I have a single line readOnly RichTextBox with wordWrap disabled, and I add programmatically one single very long line of text.

However the horizontal scrollBar does not apear, even if I set `ScrollBars` to `ForcedHorizontal`.

How can I fix this?

I can navigate through the whole line if i use the arrow keys on the keyboard, but this only makes things worse.

Comment: When I use a `RichTextBox` and give it a long string of text with `WordWrap=false`, I see the horizontal scrollbar automatically. With `ForcedHorizontal`, do you see the greyed out scrollbar when there is no text? Sanity check, is the bottom of the text box possibly cut off?

Comment: No, apparently with RichTextBox scrollbars only work with multiline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this behaviour with

```
MultiLine = false
```

If I change this property to True the scrollbar appears as expected

Comment: This works, but my text has just one line, why should multiline be necessarily?

Comment: No horizontal scrollbar in non multiline mode...thats odd

Comment: @Reniuz, yes, it's a mystery. It is stated here without much explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983606(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 12):

Try to solve it with

```
    Multiline = True
    WordWrap = False
```

Change this properties to allow the multiline feature and also allow Horizontal scrolling

Comment: For your information even these will not work if your line is all blank space.  Lets assume you have 1464 characters and your RichTextBox should display a fraction of it like 100 characters.  If the line is all blank space the horizontal scrollbar will not show even with ForcedHorinzontal.  Try it and add let say 1 at the end of the line and the scrollbar will show up by magic.

I triple test this and it's really true.  I even tried having 5 characters at the beginning, then all blank spaces until the end and no scrollbar but as soon as I type a character at the end the scrollbar appears.

Comment: If so, it's must be a bug with the default RichTextBox. If  you want it to work with white spaces only in the end of the line, inherit the default RichTextBox and fix it by your own.

Comment: in our case it's not a problem because we don't need the scrollbar.  I wrote to mention it in case people would not understand the reason why they still don't have the scrollbar.  Hope this helps others

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue with vertical scroll Bar.
If Rich textbox is inside any control like TabPage etc, than in that situation you need to set  dock ==  fill for the RickTextbox.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Set the Multiline property to true.
Check this text from MSDN:

> To display scroll bars in a RichTextBox control
>   Set the Multiline property to true. No type of scroll bar, including horizontal, will display if the Multiline property is set to false.
>
> Set the ScrollBars property to an appropriate value of the
>   RichTextBoxScrollBars enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
WordWrap = false;
ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Both;
```